# Run function on creation of class instance C#

Tags: c#, class, instance, void

I have a pice of initialiser code that should run when a new instance of a class is created, without having to be called. How would I do that ?

Update:

```
class Pice {

  public int Type;

  public void init() {

   Type = random(sudo);

  }

}
```

Now I would like the init to run only once when an instance of the class is created. So where do I put it ?

Comment: Put it in the constructor..

Comment: where is that HAHA sorry im new to c#

Comment: one moment ill update

Comment: [Using Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173115.aspx)

Comment: If the code is intended to run only once per class, it should be put in a so-called static constructor.

Comment: BTW, for your random() call - if init is initializing the the random number generator class, [make sure you do this correctly or your numbers wont be too random](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the class constructor.

```
 public class MyClass
        {
            public MyClass() 
            {
                //Initialise
            }
        }
```

Comment: well that was easy, THX

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a perfectly correct answer to a very simple question.

Answer (score 0):

Format this to fit your class name, paste into your class.cs file, and add your initialization logic.

```
public ClassName() {
    // initialization logic goes here
}
```

See [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx) for additional information.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Pice {

 public Pice(){
  this.init();
}

  public int Type;

  public void init() {

   Type = random(sudo);

  }

}
```